# Fastest (!) way to bring an illustration / painting style or texture on an *.OBJ 3d model in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, photoshop-effects

This is a *very* specific question in reference to 3D object materials and textures, and I'm kindly asking for specific answers in return beforehand: I'm not looking for general advice in this question, as I'm well aware of the wide variety of *potential* solutions.

I recently purchased a fully styleable 3D model of car:
[image]

that I'm using as an ***.OBJ** file within **Photshop**.

As the individual parts of the car are well structured I'm able to apply various textures and materials straight out of Photoshop:

[image]

All of the materials currently available to me a rather plastically and try to imitate real-life materials  (metal, plastic, fabrics even grass) as close to reality as possible after the rendering.

I do however look for a way to achieve the resemblance of more illustrative / painting style such as here: duller reflections, different shading depth and less "plastic" optic.

[image]

While I'm aware of the fact that this an illustration and not a 3D rendering and that there would be multiple solutions to getting this desired style for the end result such as:

1. Just having the car illustrated in a similar style
2. Digitally painting over the 3d model to achieve the desired style
3. Applying more or less well-done filters and Photoshop actions

**I'm wondering if there is any 3d material of texture that would at least do 80% of the job in getting the rendering away from the super clean plastic-like optic more onto an illustration style rendering as an end result?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to work with 3d in Photoshop: with anything beyond a *put a cylinder for perspective* you'll get grey hair in no time. I believe what you're looking for is NPR (Non Photo Realistic) rendering which can be achieved in different ways: from complex shaders to more simple matcaps and viewport filters. Here's an example from a free Blender (I've downloaded the model on [BlendSwap](https://www.blendswap.com/blend/1626))

Here's how the model looks in Material Preview render: I'm getting all the reflections and highlights you don't want.

[image]

However in Solid mode something interesting is happening:

[image]

By changing various settings of a viewport (`MatCap` and `Cavity`) I can make edges to pop more and change shading:

[image]

or make it almost flat:

[image]

And you can create your own MatCaps to get the effect you want:

[image]

All these effects are realtime, images can be rendered in any resolution and them composited in PS the way you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for this precise answer accompanied by image proof - I will give this attempt a shot using blender!